# 'admin' object has no attribute 'fileName'

Tags: python, csv, pyqt, qtableview

I'm trying to load my csv in QTableView and when I click on the button it gives this errorFile

> Zap Lunchies.py, line 61, in on_show_clicked
>       self.loadCsv(self.fileName)
>   AttributeError: 'admin' object has no attribute 'fileName'

This is my [code](http://pastebin.com/rxi4kfej) currently

If anyone can help that would be much appreciated. And the csv file is called  " data.csv "

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question itself (rather than just linking to it).

Comment: Sorry, will do next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__init__` function for your `admin` class needs a line

```
self.fileName = fileName
```